# how to create a ppa .dep that depends on non-default GCC?

Tags: apt, ppa, gcc

I want to create a .dep package in my PPA. That project however requires a recent GCC 4.8 or Clang 3.4+.

I found out, that you can add custom PPA dependencies, so I added ubuntu-toolchain-r/test to it.

I also specified to require gcc >= 4.8 in the debian/control file via

```
Build-Depends: g++ (>=4.8)
```

However, the build bot complains as follows:

"g++: already installed (4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 >= 4.8 is satisfied)"

and later, of course, my built fails, because it's not compiling with gcc 4.6 (precise).

So how can I convince him about my requirement ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to give a link to your ppa?

Comment: Did you try with the exact ppa version `gcc (>=4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04)` ?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~trapni/+archive/xzero - my goal (and problem) is to provide .dep's for 12.04 (basically anything that's not providing GCC >= 4.8). -- one sample failed build log: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/172753526/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.x0_0.9.0-precise1_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz

Comment: Actually, taking your second comment into account, it produces the following note in the (still failing build log): "g++: already installed (4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 >= 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04 is satisfied)". see: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/172777162/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-amd64.x0_0.9.0-0ubuntu-precise3_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz

Comment: @trapni, could you please add/include important info from comments into question. so to be complete, and I can reference back to it later in similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to depend on `g++-4.8`:

```
Build-Depends: g++-4.8
```

Comment: I always stated `g++` in my TP and comments. @Sylvain-pineau unfortunately used the term `gcc`, however, the issue remains the same.

Comment: and using g++-4.8 as a build dependency?

Comment: Using just g++ does not work as it's a metapackage not available in the ubuntu-tooolchain ppa (Dependency wait in the builder). I've updated my answer to use `g++-4.8` instead

Comment: Many thanks man. that's been it, I unfortunately cannot upvote it, but it was helpful indeed.

Comment: Cool, I up-voted your question, I should have notice the g++ instead of gcc earlier.